# wso2 API-M : how to get a token by using wso2 API-M store rest api

Tags: api, wso2

I am new to wso2 API, now, I tried to call this [Retrieve/Search applications](https://apis.wso2.com/api/am/store/v0.11/applications) at [Document address](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/apidocs/store/index.html#!/operations#ApplicationCollection#applicationsGet)

[image: My reputation is not enough, can not send pictures,please click on this link]

How to get the token in the picture?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using WSO2 API cloud, you can refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/APICloud/apidocs/store/#guide